# Shorten js script using $.each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have the following .js code which reads a json file to update the values in the html every minute.

```
$(document).ready(updateData);
function updateData() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.getJSON("data/data.json", function(result){
        $('#id1').empty();
        $('#id1').append(result.id1);
        $('#id2').empty();
        $('#id2').append(result.id2);
        $('#id3').empty();
        $('#id3').append(result.id3);
        $('#id4').empty();
        $('#id4').append(result.id4);
        $('#id5').empty();
        $('#id5').append(result.id5);
        $('#id6').empty();
        $('#id6').append(result.id6);
        $('#id7').empty();
        $('#id7').append(result.id7);
        $('#id8').empty();
        $('#id8').append(result.id8);
        $('#id9').empty();
        $('#id9').append(result.id9);
    });
    setTimeout(updateData, 60000);
}
```

Can this be rewritten in a shorter way using the $.each() function?

Comment: You can use multiple selectors as `$('#id1, #id2, #id3, #id4, #id5, #id6, #id7, #id8, #id9').empty();`. If there are only those items in `results` JSON, you can iterate over it and use the key with `#` as ID selector.

Comment: Are there other things in the json root besides the `{'id1':'..', id2:'..',...}` ?

Comment: If the code is working fine and you want it reviewed, [codereview.se] is best site. But before you do so, see [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777) and [What questions are suitable for migration to Code Review, and how does the process work?](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1687)

Comment: Yes, there are some other elements in the json root.

Comment: Are there other elements is the DOM which have an ID that begins with `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be improved using a simple `for` loop:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // 1
$(document).ready(updateData);

function updateData() {
  $.getJSON("data/data.json", function(result) {
    for (var i = 1; i<= 9; i++) {
      $('#id' + i).empty().append(result['id' + i]); // 2
    }

    setTimeout(updateData, 60000); // 3
  });
}
```

However, accessing the DOM by concatenated IDs does not look good.
For example, you can try to implement it using CSS classes and `data`-attributes.

Some minor improvements:

1. `ajaxSetup` can only be initialized once, you don't need to call it every time.
2. You probably don't need to `empty()` and `append()` at the same time. If it is a text, you can simply use `.text()`, or `.html()` for HTML.
3. It is a good idea to call `setTimeout` in your `getJSON` callback so that it updates data in 60 seconds after a previous request is **completed**, better in `.always()` handler. Imagine that one of your clients has very slow connection and it takes more than 60 seconds to load this JSON. It will lead to unexpected results.

Comment: This worked just fine. Also, thank you for the additional help! The html() function does exactly what I needed, and it actually helped me add additional functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop:

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    $('#id'+i).html(result['id'+i]);
}
```

Comment: not `.replaceWith(..)` but `.html(...)` since the OP want the original elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i =1;i<=9;i++){
$('#id'+i).empty();
$('#id'+i).append(result.id+1); }
```

This going to work

Answer (score 0):

A little more jQuery'ish, using `$.each`

```
$(document).ready(updateData);

function updateData() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    $.getJSON("data/data.json", function(result) {
        $.each("123456789".split(""), function(_,i) {
            $('#id'+i).html(result['id'+i));
        });
    }); 

    setTimeout(updateData, 60000);
}
```